# how to hash the password and get it back

Tags: passwords, hash

hey guys,
i want to hash the password so it is totally encrypted, i am able to hash the password, but now the issue is i am not able to again get back the real password, is there any way i can get the real password using any of the hash, or is there any other way to encrypt and also decrypt the text into its original content...

Please reply as soon as possible..
Thanks and regards
abbas electricwala.

Comment: you can't. A hash is one way.

Comment: You can.. by brute force and a whole host of other [faster, smarter and more efficient methods](http://hashcat.net/). The key is that hashing doesn't make the password impossible to recover, but *difficult*. The *degree* to how difficult is the most important element of any hashing of a password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of hashing a password is so that you do not have to save passwords in clear text. If someone can get the hashed passwords, he can't convert them back to passwords. Also, don't forget to [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) your hashing otherwise your hashed passwords are vulnerable to [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_tables#Defense_against_rainbow_tables).

Answer (score 8):

Hash is a one way encryption - that's the point - not to be able to get the original information from it. Hash is meant for verifying integrity. You can check if a entered string is the correct password by hashing and comparing the hashes with the one you had before.

Comment: i think you'll find my comment to OP was faster! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Hashing isn't encryption, you cannot reverse it. You use hashing to check whether someone has a specific password, without knowing the password yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of hash functions is, to make it **impossible** to reconstruct the orignal data from the hash. Furthermore there are infinite different inputs to a hash function giving the same result.

If you want to check if a password entered in, say a login form matches the valid passwort, hash the newly input password and compare the hashes.

Answer (score 1):

You typically can't and shouldn't. You also hash the received password and compare the two hashes

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically once the data is converted using a one-way hash function, the hashed version of the data cannot be used to recreate the original data.
You may want to try a brute force attack against the hash code, using a dictionary. It naturally helps if you know which hash function has been used.

Comment: thnx guys for your response, my query is now resolved. thanks a lot.